# how to fork and enable merge revision in AWS codecommit

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

A repo in AWS has some branches, I would like to fork the last active dev branch and make a pull request to the owner of the account so that he could analyse and accept the merge. How can I do that?  I can't know how I fork this private repo, and send a pull-request in command line, someone could clear that idea?

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing that you are comparing with fork option provided by GitHub. CodeCommit doesn't support forking a repository. As I understand forking works with pubic repositories but in CodeCommit there is no public repository.